# How to handle queue data in c#

Tags: c#, queue, communication

I have 2 processes to communicate with.

One of them is sending data every 5ms, and other process is receiving data every 50ms using Queue.

When I start to send data, I can check the queue count is increasing because the difference the interval. So even if I stop sending data, the receive process is still working because the queue is still queued.

Here is the code the object communicating:

```
public Lens[] GetNum()
{
    if (Queue.Count() < 1)
    {
        return null;
    }else 
    {
        var n = Queue.Dequeue();
        return n;
    }
}
```

I want to receive data with low latency without clearing the queue. what should i edit the code?

Comment: There is [`Queue.Peek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue.peek?view=netcore-3.1) which returns the first object without dequeueing it. But why do you not want your queue to clear? It will eventually fill up take up a lot of RAM

Comment: @MindSwipe If i do clear the queue, is that okay to add a code 'Queue.Clear()' between var n = Queue.Dequeue() and return n?

Comment: "I want to receive data with low latency without clearing the queue." and that makes no sense. Queue data being consumed will clear it. If you do not consume it , why push it.

Comment: @Jacob but *why* would you do that? dequeue removes the thing that it returns - if you call `Clear`, you're throwing away anything *else* in the queue that *hasn't* been processed

Answer (score 2):

> without clearing the queue

Not sure what you mean by that, so I'm largely ignoring it; the entire point of a queue is to clear it; since queues are FIFO, if you don't clear it, you're always processing the same item.

---

If you can, perhaps look at `System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T>`, which is an optimized, thread-safe, asynchronous queue-like mechanism designed for producer/consumer interaction in asynchronous code, with all the options re bounded/unbounded, activation, etc, baked in.

---

Back in the synchronous world:

Firstly, note that `Queue<T>` is *not* thread-safe; since you are using multiple threads you, here *must* synchronize access, most likely using a `lock` (`Monitor`).

If you mean you are *checking* the queue on a poll (timer), then you can reduce latency by signalling between the threads. For example, if you're adding to an empty queue, then the worker might be waiting, so: *pulse them*:

```cs
// consumer
lock (queue)
{
    while (queue.Count == 0)
    {   // relinquishes lock, and waits
        // for timeout or pulse
        Monitor.Wait(queue, timeout);
    }
    return queue.Dequeue(); // to be processed
}

// producer
lock (queue)
{
    queue.Enqueue(work);
    if (queue.Count == 1)
    {
        Monitor.Pulse(queue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Queues are not LIFO, they are FIFO but your description of "if you don't clear it, you're always processing the same item" is correct for FIFO, but not for LIFO data structures (assuming whatever produced the data for the LIFO structure is continuously producing data)

Comment: @MindSwipe doh, brain-fart there a second; I meant FIFO